# Python: Google Drive Authentification and folder

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I have a python script to match files on google drive in specific folder. It worked fine with my GSuite account in the company. But If i want to use it at home with my simple Google Drive account it's not working. No files found:

Here is my code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from apiclient import errors
import io
from apiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from apiclient import errors
import os 
import csv

try :
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

folder_id = 'XYZ00000'


SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()    
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    print("Create new data storage file ...")
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = client.OOB_CALLBACK_URN
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags) \
            if flags else tools.run(flow, store)
    print ("Storage")
DRIVE = build('drive', 'v2', http=creds.authorize(Http()))


def getKeywordsID():
    page_token = None

    while True:
        response = DRIVE.files().list(q="'XYZ00000' in parents and trashed = false",
                                              spaces='drive',
                                              fields='nextPageToken, items(id, title)',
                                              pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('items', []):
            if ('test.txt' == file.get('title')):
                print ('test.txt on Google Drive found')

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
        if page_token is None:
            break;
    return file_id    

# Download file
file_id = getKeywordsID()
if file_id != None:
    request = DRIVE.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.FileIO('test.txt', 'wb')
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download test.txt %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100) ) 
else:
    print ("File not found.")
```

I have no idea why it's not working. I enabled Google Drive API, created a project, added an OAuth2.0 client ID (select “Other” as option) and downloaded the json file for storage.

Comment: How do you mean it's not working? Is there any specific output/error displayed?

Comment: Error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_id' referenced before assignment . But it's not because the variable. It is because the folder or files cannot be found. With my other company account it work's fine. I dont't know why ...

Comment: Does this error come up on line "request = DRIVE.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)" ? On a side note you might wanna change file_id != None to file_id is not None since the latter performs an identity check and not an equality check.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "QC_SB_AMSS_UpdateGoogleDrive.py", line 307, in <module>
    main()
  File "QC_SB_AMSS_UpdateGoogleDrive.py", line 240, in main
    downloadFile()
  File "QC_SB_AMSS_UpdateGoogleDrive.py", line 220, in downloadFile
    file_id = getKeywordsID()
  File "QC_SB_AMSS_UpdateGoogleDrive.py", line 216, in getKeywordsID
    return file_id
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_id' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback posted, I can see that in the `getKeywordsID` function you are returning the `file_id` variable, which you have not initialized in the `getKeywordsID` function scope. Hence the `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file_id' referenced before assignment` is thrown.

Comment: Yes but with my other company google drive account it work's fine and the main problem is that no file found. But there are files in the folder on google drive.

Comment: Is file_id the variable you intend to return or something like file.id instead? Because file_id is not referenced/used anywhere else in that function.

Comment: forget file_id. This is not the problem. The problem is here: response = DRIVE.files().list(q="'XYZ0000 in parents and trashed = false",
                                              spaces='drive',
                                              fields='nextPageToken, items(id, title)',
                                              pageToken=page_token).execute() or here: for file in response.get('items', []): Or something with my google drive account

Comment: Ok, but the traceback begs to differ. What I don't understand is where do you get the `file_id` value from before returning it.

Comment: I deleted the if-else statement in the function where I get the file_id. But this is not the reason of error. I tried other code and get this error: raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self._uri) googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/XYZ0000?alt=media returned "The authenticated user h as not granted the app 83767465635 read access to the file XYZ0000">

Comment: If you look up this error in [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors), you will find out that you must explicitly open the file with this Drive app. So I think there's your answer.

Comment: And how? With my other google drive account from company it work's fine

Comment: Have you actually opened the file using the drive app with your home gdrive account as suggested in the link? Please look at the link I provided and try both corrective actions mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem but now it can only find xlsx-files that are imported by python code. Other files not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161093/discussion-between-kingjulian-and-tigerclaw).

Comment: The error comes from here: SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
If I am using drive.files I get only file that are uploaded by python. But then I have permission problems ....